# library socket: open port

Tags: python, sockets, port

I have try to create a little online game with python but I face a problem.

I have no problem as long as I work in local (same computer or private IP adresse) but the socket can't connect if i use an IP.

Server:

```
import socket

co_prin = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
co_prin.bind(('', 9000))
co_prin.listen(10)
co,info=co_prin.accept()

print('connexion recu')

co.close()
co_prin.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

co_serv=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
adresse='81.56.76.61'
co_serv.connect((adresse, 9000))
print("Connecté.")
co_serv.close()
```

If I change adresse by 'localhost' there is no problem.

One tell me that the reason was python can't open the port. I would like to know if there is a solution to solve or bypass the problem easy to use for other user. (I can always create a local network with hamachi or open the port manually but it's wouldn't be easy to share my programm).

Edit, the error in the client code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in 
    co_serv.connect((adresse, 9000))
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: When you say 'if I use an IP', do you mean in the client or the server?

Comment: Are you sure `81.56.76.61` is the right address? This code works for me.

Comment: I use an IP int the client.

I get it on http://www.mon-ip.com/, I can try to get it on another site.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your actual computer IP. You are using your *public* IP address.

Open cmd/command.com and type in the command: `ipconfig`.

You will there see a totally different IP (*IPv4/IPv6 address*):

[image]

Most likely you want this (do this for yourself!):
[image]

Then, if you want people outside your network want to access your computer you must port forward the port to your network IP address from your router.

If you are just experimenting with python, it's best to use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as IP-address.

Comment: The problem was to pass from connection in the network to oustide.
Thanks for your explanation. I will try to port forward.

Comment: No problem, please mark it as resolved so others know as well.